# How to setup up PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable on Mac?

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I am trying to setup Django to use MySQL. I am getting the following error when I type in `localhost/mysite`

```
ExtractionError at /
Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/WebServer/.python-eggs'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  /Library/WebServer/.python-eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.
```

From the error message I know that I have to change the `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` environment variable to point to a directory that Apache can access. I tried adding the following to `httpd.conf`

```
SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and also just `SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /var/www` to `bashrc`, but nothing seems to resolve the problem. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Note: `www` is a folder that I created

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also might try to set the egg cache directory in the wsgi script,

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/usr/local/pylons/python-eggs'
```

as can be found from here
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues

Answer (score 1):

Based on your previous question, you're using WSGI. You want [`WSGIPythonEggs`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonEggs) or the `python-eggs` option for [`WSGIDaemonProcess`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess).