# django ExtractionError at /

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am brand new to web app development. I'm having a problem with django after starting my application. I get the following error:

```
ExtractionError at /
Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/pylons'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  /usr/local/pylons/python-eggs
```

After following some other answers, I added:

```
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/usr/local/pylons/python-eggs'
```

To my sites wsgi file. Still same error. I am new to apache and I don't know how to "Give permissions to the apache user". How exactly do I do this? I am on OSX Mountain lion.

Comment: Why have you tagged this as `django` when you are clearly using Pylons?

Comment: This error message shows up when I visit my django localhost webpage.

Comment: In which case, what are you doing with Pylons eggs? They are two completely separate web frameworks.

Comment: I have the same error as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107016/how-to-setup-up-python-egg-cache-environment-variable-on-mac Per haps that will give you more information as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like apache is serving a different website. Try starting the django development server by using `python manage.py runserver` then pointing your browser to `localhost:8000`, which is where your django site should be on the development server.

Comment: I don't think so. When I opened the apache site before creating the application, it loaded the django welcome page perfectly fine. This error is happening since starting the application.

Comment: What do you mean by 'starting the application'? It's not a django concept I'm familiar with.

Comment: I meant after I create an application. using: python manage.py startapplication xxx

Comment: Okay. That shouldn't necessarily cause a problem. Did you try my original answer? If so, what happened?

Comment: Tried. I get a NameError at /. That's probably because my urls isn't writter properly.. Still doesn't explain the error I get on apache.

Comment: Indeed, but it has solved the problem this question relates to. I'm now completely sure apache is serving a Pylons application you, or someone else with access to your machine, has written in the past. The information on the name error should point you in the direction of solving your new problem ;-)