# python error access denied

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I'm having a problem trying to run a project with pydev python .. it returns me the following error

> The Following error occurred while trying to extract file (s) to the
>   Python egg  cache:
>
> [Error 5] Access is denied:
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python-Eggs\mysql_python-1.2.4-py2.7-win32.egg-tmp\_mysql.pyd'
>
> The Python egg cache directory is currently Set to:
>
> C: \ Users \ Administrator \ AppData \ Roaming \ Python-Eggs
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory? you
>   can  change the cache directory by setting the environment
>   PYTHON_EGG_CACHE  variable to point to an accessible directory.

Before functioned normal however the python 2.6 has installed in my computer .. after that started to give this error ... can someone help me? i have the python27

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup up PYTHON\_EGG\_CACHE environment variable on Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107016/how-to-setup-up-python-egg-cache-environment-variable-on-mac)